# R3F / three.js - Instanciate a combination of objects

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

In the [following codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-goodall-99upv?file=/src/App.jsx):
[image]

there are different geometries merged together thanks to [drei library](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei) (2Boxes and 1 Sphere).

I would like to

1. have a lot of this new geometry with a good performances. I think the solution would be to instanciate the merged geometry but I do not know how to do it.
2. Still be able to control each part properties (for example, make a cube bigger than the other one in a special instance)

Could you please help me ?

Comment: For 2., I'd rather used batching, than instancing. But I don't know how to implement it in r3f

Comment: Do you mean the `merge` in three.js ? I am not sure what you are talking about when refering to `batching`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to:

- Create an `instanceMesh` for each part of the geometry
- Assemble each part by changing each geometry position

You can find this solution with 2 codeSandboxes:

- [one](https://codesandbox.io/live/a81ed74e476?file=/src/components/segment.jsx) using the `Drei` librairy but which get laggy around 10k elements
- [one](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-three-fiber-poc-segments-i3l76c?file=/src/components/segment.jsx) using `instanceMesh` from R3F which work pretty well with 100k elements.

I do not know if we can improve more the performance, but it seems to work pretty well like this.